# Watir-webdriver and Chrome57; can no longer use `browser.window`

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, rspec, automation, watir-webdriver

I'm doing some automation with Watir-webdriver, Chromedriver (v2.27), and Chrome (v57)

My spec_helper has a line of code that reads `@browser.window.maximize`

Since updating to Chrome v57, this no longer runs as I get the following error back

```
Asset Section EULA and Intended Use The asset section behaves like eula and intended use EULA and Intended Use clicks Download and sees intended Use
 Failure/Error: @browser.window.maximize

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: cannot get automation extension
   from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
     (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
 Shared Example Group: "eula and intended use" called from ./spec/smoke/public_view/asset_section_dl_share_spec.rb:65
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:252:in `maximizeWindow'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/window.rb:117:in `maximize'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:96:in `block in maximize'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:73:in `window'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:200:in `use'
 # /Users/kmancusi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:96:in `maximize'
 # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From my #spec_helper:

```
chrome_prefs = {
'profile' => {
  'default_content_setting_values' => { 'automatic_downloads' => 1 }
  }
}

config.before(:all) do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => chrome_prefs, switches: %w(--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate)
  @browser.window.maximize
  @browser.goto site
end
```

I am fairly confident updating to v57 caused this.  It was working *before* I updated, and--as of right now--if I comment out `@browser.window.maximize` it runs

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and initially fixed it by removing the browser.window.maximize and adding the following to switches:

```
--start-maximized
```

The issue was then fixed in ChromeDriver version 2.28 (Latest is now 2.29).

ChromeDriver 2.28 fix notes included the following:

```
Fixes a bug which blocked ChromeDriver automation extension from loading and thereby causing window resizing/positioning & screenshot functionalities to break.
```

And can be downloaded [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Also check the test output to ensure that you are actually using the new driver you have downloaded, you'll see something like "Starting ChromeDriver 2.xx.xxxxxx".  You might have some configuration that is pointing to an old version of ChromeDriver.

Comment: Hmm.... I updated and restarted chromedriver to v2.29 and changed my switches to now read as `switches: %w(--start-maximized --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate)`, my tests do not start in a maximized window

Comment: Shouldn't switches be within an array, so square brackets: switches: %w[--start-maximized --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]

Comment: Did some additional playing around.  I can use something like `--start-fullscreen` and it takes up the entire screen.  When I use `--start-maximized` it only has a browser screen size of 1011x1059.  Is there a way to modify what "maximized" is referred to?

Comment: There is a separate switch which can be used to set the windows size: --ash-host-window-bounds="1024x768" as an example.